# Getting java.security.AccessControlException on on calling getWidth() method of java.awt.image.RenderedImage class

Tags: java, security, applet, awt, jai

Getting java.security.AccessControlException on calling getWidth() method of java.awt.image.RenderedImage class.

Code which is causing problem

```
new Dimension(this.image.getWidth(), this.image.getHeight())
```

In the above code this.image  is of type java.awt.image.RenderedImage class

Full stack trace

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.com.sun.media.jai.util")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkPackageAccessHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javax.media.jai.ScaleOpImage.layoutHelper(ScaleOpImage.java:228)
    at javax.media.jai.ScaleOpImage.(ScaleOpImage.java:437)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.ScaleNearestBinaryOpImage.(ScaleNearestBinaryOpImage.java:77)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.ScaleCRIF.create(ScaleCRIF.java:123)
    ... 33 more
```

**NOTE:**

I have added following lines into my java.policy file

```
 permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.*";
 permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.com.sun.media.jai.opimage";
```

Still it didn't work. Has anyone faced this issue?  I am running applet on jre version 1.8.0_45

**UPDATE:**

Same code will work fine with Java 7 if we add following entry to java.policy file

```
permission java.util.PropertyPermission com.sun.media.imageio.disableCodecLib", "read";
```

Comment: *"I have added following lines into my java.policy file"*  Policy files are useless when it comes to deployment, and every applet these days needs to be digitally signed in order to have any chance of being launched in a browser.  As such, I would recommend putting functionality into the build to also sign it, and go from there (ignoring the policy files).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Thanks a lot for the reply. Applet build I am using is signed only.

Comment: *"Applet build I am using is signed only."*  Make sure it declares `all-permissions` in the manifest and then the policy files are irrelevant.

Comment: @AndrewThompson  I already have following entry in my MANIFEST.MF
Permissions: all-permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got  it working. Following are the details of fixes I have done

1] Add `permission:all-permissions` to MANIFEST.MF: Actually my applet jar  already had this entry in its manifest. But  my jar  had dependencies on jai-core, jai-imageio and jai-codec jars which didn't had this entry. So I generated  a uber jar using maven shade plugin so that my applet jar and  all its dependencies will be  packaged inside one single jar  and refer to its manifest which will have entry `permission:all-permissions` in it's manifest

2] After doing step 1 I was  getting  `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.com.sun.media.jai.util")`

This exception can be resolved in 2 ways

a] By adding entry `permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.com.sun.media.jai.util";`  to java.policy file which can be found  at location `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\security`

This approach is not so cool as it requires modification of java.policy file in every client system. So I used alternate approach of implementing PrivilegedAction as described  in approach b

b] By implementing PrivilegedAction you  have to implement it's run() method. All the code inside run() method will execute with privileges enabled so that  you won't get any AccessControlException.  You identify the  code  throwing AccessControlException and put that code inside overridden run() method so that the code will have necessary privileges.

For exaple in my case following code was throwing AccessControlException

```
graphics2d.drawRenderedImage(image, new AffineTransform());
```

To fix it I have created a  private class in my class and implemented PrivilegedAction like below

```
 private final class DrawRenderedImage implements PrivilegedAction
{
    private Graphics2D graphics2D = null;

    public DrawRenderedImage(Graphics2D graphics)
    {
        graphics2D = graphics;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Object run()
    {

            graphics2D.drawRenderedImage(image, new AffineTransform());


        return new Boolean(true);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have put the code which was causing problem inside run method.  Now run  method can be invoked like below

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new DrawRenderedImage(graphics2d));
```

Here  AccessController class will invoke run method of PrivilegedAction instance.

By doing  this you don't have to put permissions in java.policy file as mentioned in approach a